# PHP WebSocket Async task

Tags: php, multithreading, asynchronous, pthreads, zeromq

I have the following scenario:
I have a WebSocket running with Ratchet (PHP WebSocket)
I use the onMessage() callback function to handle incomming data and respond accordingly.
If I get the 'start-broadcast' message via the WebSocket I have to start a loop which will send out a broadcast message to all connected clients on the WebSocket every 0.2 sec. So I need to make a loop which can do this, but I can't put it into the onMessage() function, as this will block, and I won't be able to receive any more messages via the WS.
If I get the 'stop-broadcast' message via the WebSocket I have to stop the broadcast loop.

So basically I need a way to start and stop this loop, and have this loop running parallel to the WebSocket loop so it doesn't block up.

Problems: The Socket->send() method I'm pretty sure is not thread-safe, so I need to make sure that the WS loop and my broadcast loop are not trying to send a message at the same time.

Possible approaches I have considered:

- **ReactPHP/Promise**
  Somehow use this to make an async function inside which I have a loop. I have no experience with Promise, and I don't know if it can do what I need.
- **Running a spearate PHP-CLI process**, and use **ZMQ** for inter-process communication between the WS instance and the Broadcast loop.
  With this I could send message back and forth from the websocket, and
  I could send a message to start or stop the broadcast, also I could
  send a message from the broadcast loop to the WS loop to send out a
  message to the WS clients.
- **Using pthreads**
  Spawn a new Thread for the broadcast loop, this can be killed when I
  want it to stop. I'm pretty sure I'll have to make sure the Socket is
  only used by one thread at a time, so I'll have handle that somehow.

**My question is, which approach should I take, and are there any examples or tutorials for the suggested approach?**

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right:

- You get in a web-socket - command "start"
- After receiving the request, you want to start broadcasting with 0.2
  seconds interval
- If you will come - command "stop", you need to stop broadcasting

Maybe I misunderstood the problem, but it's a bad idea, getting client requests start and stop brodcasting (what if everyone will send a "start command"?)

**In general, I would recommend using ZMQ. This is the most scalable solution. (It is best to separate the services)**

- You start the server.
- Waiting for commands from ZMQ, that you need to start broadcasting.
- Once you get a command of ZMQ, create a timer with 0.2 second intervals and broadcasts
- As soon as you get "command" stop in ZMQ - kill the timer.

OR

- Your start the server ZMQ PUB and start brodcasting
- Yout start web-socket
- You give command start and start receive ZMQ SUB messages
- You give command stop and stop receive ZMQ SUB messages

If you want a pub/sub service. Then simply create a Timer and have a list of who to broadcast. Client send "subscribe", and receive messages. Good idea use Redis for storing data between processes (WebSocket - ZMQ)

You need read [ZMQ PHP DOC](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:all), before using ZMQ and see [reactphp/zmq](https://github.com/reactphp/zmq) lib

Comment: In this case its not a bad idea to get client requests start and stop broadcasting. This is for a program controlling a race. Multiple clients are connected, but only one initiates the race, and when someone wins, they stop the race. The broadcasted data are the speed data for the racers taken from sensor devices. If multiple racers send the start command, it doesn't do anything bad, it simply flips a bit controlling whether or not to broadcast speed data from the sensors.

Comment: Thank you though for your feedback, I chose to go with the ZMQ solution.